# Rstudio: Crear histogramas de frecuencia y frecuencia acumulada a partir de datos de tabla

Tags: rstudio

me dieron el gráfico de un histograma. De ahí calcule las frecuencias abssolutas de cada clase y la frecuencia acumulada también. Me gustaría saber como construir en R los histogramas de frecuencia y frecuencia acumulada a partir de dichos datos.

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolví mi duda, debo concatenar los datos máximos de cada clase en un vector (en el caso de la primera clase el mínimo): `x<-c(0, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40)`, luego armo mi histograma con los breaks adecuados: `hist(x, freq = F, breaks = 5, ylab='fi', main='Histograma de frecuencia de X')`.